# Sliding effect its not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying custom navigation, for that sliding effect its not working as expected. Please look at my code and let me know your suggestion.

**[Demo LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/prabunivas/Fy9Hs/4/)**

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:320px;height:320px;border:1px solid red;">
  <div id="col1" style="float:left">
    <div id="menu">Slide DIV</div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div>This content will display on page load. <br/>
      Onclick of "Slide" button this entire thing will move to right side and Menu div should slide in from left but now it just displaying without sliding effect.
      <input type="button" id="slide-btn" value="Slide"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#menu{display:none}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide-btn').click(function(){
        $('#menu').css({'display':'block','width':'170px','border':'1px solid blue','height':'320px'});
        $('#menu').show("slide",{direction:"up"},2000);

    });
});
```

### picture representation references here

http://www.mobile-patterns.com/custom-navigation
http://img2.mobile-patterns.com/img/320/1398782204339-2014-04-29%2010.35.53.png

Comment: You have to include jQuery UI in order for `show()` to support animations.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fy9Hs/6/

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `#menu` width to 170, which is already at it's target width. Set your width to 0, then animate the width.

```
$('#menu').css({'display':'block','width':'0','border':'1px solid blue','height':'320px'});
$('#menu').animate({width:170},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide-btn').click(function(){
        $('#menu').animate({width:'toggle'}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use Jquery UI js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slide-btn').click(function () {
        $('#menu').toggle("slide", 1000);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy9Hs/8/)

Comment: For job related in web

Comment: @saina you need or referring job for me

Answer (score 0):

use animate to do nice sliding, Here code for Slide In and Out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').css({'display':'none','border':'1px solid blue','height':'320px'});
    $('#slide-btn').click(function(){        
        if($('#menu').is(":visible")){        
            $('#menu').animate({width:'0px'}).hide(100);
        }
        else{            
            $('#menu').show().animate({width:'170px'});
        }
    });
});
```